# Embed HTML into an email message

Tags: java, email, blackberry, html-email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multipart email message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721220/multipart-email-message)

I want to embedded HTML content on email message body.  I have tried to search but didn't get any solution.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The default value of 'Content-Type' in an email is set to 'text/plain'

You have to set this value to 'text/html' for it to treat the email's content as HTML.

This is applicable no matter what language/platform you are using to send the email.

In Java Mail API, it would look something like this:

```
String content= "<html><body><b>Hello!</b></body></html>"    // html content

Properties props = new Properties();
// put properties

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setContent(content, "text/html");    // sets the content type to HTML
```

Comment: I have tried this code but when I using MimeMessage and Properties api,It is showing error message "create Properties and MimeMessage"  and on BB eclipse message.setContent(content, "text/html");  only take one parameter

Comment: Are you using Java Mail API? Could you paste the link to the API you are currently using?

Comment: Message m = new Message();  m.setContent("\n no History");m.setSubject("Category");
          Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));  I am using this I want to attach html view on body,  how will attach Please help

Comment: Please provide the link to the Java API you are using
Eg: http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html
It would help a lot to have some documentation to read

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't search so far.

Try it with JavaMail API, here's an easy and effectivetutorial  : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: I have saw that url already  (MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);) this api is not available on Blackberry java

Comment: And so what ? You get the solution, and you still ask for ?

Comment: I want to attach html content on body part in Blackberry

Comment: I am using this type Message m = new Message();
   try {
      m.setContent("<h1>This is actual message</h1>" );
    m.setSubject("Category");
          Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(m));
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: but this is not working html tag also coming

Comment: I want to only text not html tags